# Cannot append icon to jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uidatepicker

I am creating an extension plugin to the jQuery UI Date Picker plugin mostly to just standardize the options used, as well as to add an icon to open the calendar.  I am aware of the plugin's use of an icon trigger, but this will not work, as I am using an icon in my sprite image and not wanting an additional request for a mere icon.

My plugin code:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.fn, {
        DatePicker: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                    selectOtherMonths: true
                }).after(
                    $("<a/>", { "href": "javascript:void(0)", "class": "icon-calendar", "text": "select date" }).click(function() {
                        $(this).prev("input").datepicker("show")
                    })
                )
            })
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

This works for everthing except producing the icon, so to test the code, I added the after function after the initialization of the plugin.

```
$(".date").DatePicker().after(
    $("<a/>", { "href": "javascript:void(0)", "class": "icon-calendar", "text": "select date" }).click(function() {
        $(this).prev("input").datepicker("show")
    })
)
```

This is where it really perplexes me as this code does work to produce the calendar icon. while I could get it to work this way, it is obviously not the better choice as it should be part of the extension plugin and not get repeated in all of my various implementations of the plugin.

Comment: Well, I ended up using your hack and sticking it in a utility UI element JS class I had  so at least I don't have to think about it anymore and when jQuery gets their act together with sprites for these things I'll only have 1 place to change.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `.datepicker({...`

```
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
```

So:

```
$.extend($.fn, {
    DatePicker: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).datepicker({
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/D7tKe/

Comment: I had mentioned in my post, "I am aware of the plugin's use of an icon trigger, but this will not work, as I am using an icon in my sprite image and not wanting an additional request for a mere icon"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.ui-datepicker').append('<a href="#">My link</a>');
```

Comment: .append("<a href='javscript:void(0)' class='icon-calendar'>select date</a>"); // appends it, but doesn't show because it is invalid markup between <input></input> as input is supposed to self-terminate

Comment: .after("<a href='javscript:void(0)' class='icon-calendar'>select date</a>"); // still doesn't work, nothing shows after item

Comment: .parent().append("<a href='javscript:void(0)' class='icon-calendar'>select date</a>") // Tried this as the input is always at the end of the parent element which should operate the same as .after() in that instance, but still doesn't work